# Get latest single row for most recent date

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working with Oracle 10g. I have a table TABLE_X with following data:

```
             **Sup_ID     Start_Date     End_Date**
               S001       01-01-2010     31-12-2020
               S001       01-01-2011     31-12-2019
               S001       01-01-2012     31-12-2018
               S002       01-01-2010     31-12-2014
               S002       01-01-2014     31-12-2015
               S003       01-01-2012     30-09-2013
               S004       01-01-2010     31-12-2014
               S004       01-01-2011     31-12-2013
```

Now I need to write a SQL Query to get each Sup_ID with  most latest start and end date and the result would be like following:

```
            **Sup_ID     Start_Date        End_Date**
              S001       01-01-2012        31-12-2018
              S002       01-01-2014        31-12-2015
              S003       01-01-2012        30-09-2013
              S004       01-01-2011        31-12-2013
```

Note that I am using Oracle DBMS. Can anyone help me in this regard?
Thanks to you all.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: -1 You did not try anything so we can see where you are going wrong and need help. You did not explain in anywhere *near* enough detail how you got your result table (of particular note is the choice of `S004`'s `End_Date`, and how this is treated differently to `S002`).

Answer (score 3):

A simple [**max()**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions085.htm) aggregate function should solve the problem

```
select *
from Table1
where ("Sup_ID", "Start_Date") in (select "Sup_ID", max("Start_Date") 
                       from Table1
                       group by "Sup_ID");
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43513/4)

Comment: What will be the output of `S004`?

Comment: @RagingBull Corrected.. I mis read the question as latest start and latest end date..

Comment: @Gone : next time....read correctly in 1st time mate!! ;) :p

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT T2.Sup_ID,T1.Start_Date,T2.End_Date
FROM TableName T1 JOIN
(SELECT Sup_ID,MAX(End_Date) as End_Date
 FROM TableName
 GROUP BY Sup_ID) T2 ON T1.Sup_ID=T2.Sup_ID AND T1.End_Date=T2.End_Date
ORDER BY T2.Sup_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from 
(
select *,rn=row_number()over(partition by Sup_ID order by Start_Date desc) from table
)x
where x.rn=1
```